# Noise abduction for computing counterfactuals

Tags: causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram, counterfactuals

Given observational data $X$ and knowledge of the true causal graph structure $\mathcal{G}$. How does abduction of the exogenous noise ($U$) for computing counterfactuals work?

We don't have data about the unobserved noise variables $U$ and we do not know the structural equations $\mathcal{F}$ - i.e. $f_i$ for each endogenous variable $X_i$. So how can we ever infer the exogenous noise $U_i$ for any particular $X_i$?

For more context about this topic:

This question refers to contents similar to, for example, the following Structural Causal Model (SCM) in Section 4.2 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.02499.pdf

or more general Section 4.1.4 in the book Elements of Causal Inferene: https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/id/056a11be-ce3a-44b9-8987-a6c68fce8d9b/11283.pdf

Comment: I don't think you can do abduction at all without the structural equations. If you have them, you should be able to do it.

Comment: How does the literature do it then based on only observational data $X$ and causal graph structure $\mathcal{G}$?
If we assume there are no noise variables $U$: It seems reasonable to compute parameters of structural equations $f_i$ between observed variables $X$. I was wondering whether the research literature assumes that the noise $U_i$ is *additive* and thus the parameters $\beta_{U_{i}}$ in the structural equations $f_i$ must always be equal to 1.0? Meaning that there is no need to learn the parameters for the additive noise variables $U_i$ of each structural equation $f_i$?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me in either document to which you linked that the authors are attempting to do abduction without structural equations. In the first one, for example, with Pearl's method, there are structural equations listed. In the second doc, the word "abduction" isn't even present in any of its 289 pages. So I'm confused: where are people trying to abduct without structural equations?

Comment: These were just examples about the topic in general. If you are interested in examples where this is done, you can have a look at the following two papers:
1. See section E (Appendix ) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.14690.pdf and
2. See Section 6 (Experiments) in https://openreview.net/pdf?id=4FU8Jz1Oyj

Comment: So for your example 1, Appendix E, which example is running abduction without equations? I'm seeing structural equations all over the place there. Similarly, Section 6 in the second paper has equations for both examples.

Comment: @AdrianKeister in the first resource (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.14690.pdf) the authors explain in Section 4 (see second sentence onwards as well as Definition 4.1) that the underlying SCM $\mathcal{M}$ is unknown and that the only assumption is that one has access to a) the true causal graph (as an adjacency matrix $A$) and b) the endogenous variables $X$ i.e. observational data. 

(I referred to Appendix E to show what structural equations are used to generate data $X$. So just to be clear: these equations are not used/known when fitting SCM and computing the counterfactuals.)

Comment: Well, they're using the VACA to approximate the abduction step, not computing it directly. It's a ML algorithm used to approximate things.

Comment: Yeah and I wonder how that is theoretically even possible as we don't have any data to work with when it comes to inferring the exogenous variables U as well as their parameters in the structural equations.

Answer (score 0):

### How can we obtain the noise variable values without knowing the structural equations?

The short answer is we cannot obtain them, at least not without further assumptions.

- [The paper on counterfactual explanations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.02499.pdf) gives structural equations for their experiments (section 6), and they do seem to assume additive noise as you suggest.
- The [VACA paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.14690.pdf) tries to tackle exactly your question empirically. They design their VAE in a way that the latent space should hopefully be something like the latent noise variables and give empirical evidence to support this.
  It's not theoretical work, instead they test their method on a handful of synthetic datasets. Although their approach seems sophisticated, their results can hardly be seen as conclusive evidence on the question.

In summary, I'd say your question is an open one. There may be some suitable assumptions under which we can determine or at least bound the noise variables, and there may be some ways to achieve good empirical results on important real-world datasets. Time will tell, but for now computing counterfactuals given the structure but without the equations is not really a thing as far as I can tell.